# How to change text from unlink button in odoo?

Tags: templates, overriding, odoo, action-button

I am working on odoo 11, In the tree view from res.user I need to change the action button text from "Delete" to "Active/Inactive", just the text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change using **translation** in system and change parameter according to your requirement.

Comment: No, is not a problem with the translation, the project has to be in spanish, but i need to change it from "Suprimir" (Delete) to "Activo/Inactivo" (Active/Inactive)

Comment: Ok Then Replace string Suprimir" (Delete) to "Activo/Inactivo" (Active/Inactive) in translation

Comment: but if i do that, then wont it change it as well it in every model?